# Combine all test using CMake

Tags: c, unit-testing, cmake

I'm using CMake to build and testing my .c code. I've created the test individually, but there's some point missing. I'd like to combine all of this test, so it only run once. As you know too, if this run separately, if the test success it will tell tester 100% 1/1 4 times, how to merge/combine all of this test, so it will tell 100% 4/4 1 times

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(my_project)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(my_project main.c)

enable_testing()

add_test(NAME build_test COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .)

add_test(NAME run_test COMMAND my_project)
set_tests_properties(run_test PROPERTIES DEPENDS build_test)

add_test(NAME output_test COMMAND my_project 3)
set_tests_properties(output_test PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "Hello, World!\nHello, World!\nHello, World!")

add_test(NAME output_test2 COMMAND my_project 5)
set_tests_properties(output_test2 PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "Hello, World!\nHello, World!\nHello, World!\nHello, World!\nHello, World!\n")
```

main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Hello, World!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output if the test run separately (not combined) will be like this (just example, picking one the shortest)

```
[ctest]     Start 1: build_test
[ctest] 1/1 Test #1: build_test .......................   Passed    0.55 sec
[ctest] 
[ctest] 100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1
```

I'm expecting like this

```
[ctest]     Start 1: run_test
[ctest] 4/4 Test #1: run_test .......................   Passed    0.55 sec
[ctest] 
[ctest] 100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 4
```

Or maybe if there's fault from the output, so the score isn't 100%

```
[ctest]     Start 1: run_test
[ctest] 4/4 Test #1: run_test .......................   Passed    0.55 sec
[ctest] 
[ctest] 75% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 4
```

Comment: If you build your software within a test, what happens when you run tests in parallel?

Comment: If you run `ctest`, then all tests should be executed, one by one. And you will got `100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 4`. I don't get your problem.